# Redux store double nesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im getting double nested state after api call. Here is it.

[Screenshot from redux devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9UgE.png)

Here are my actions

```js
export const getUserSuccess = user => ({
  type: GET_USER_SUCCESS,
  user,
});

export const getUserFailure = error => ({
  type: GET_USER_FAILURE,
  error,
});

export const getUserRequest = () => (
  dispatch => (
    axios.get('./user.json')
      .then(response => dispatch(getUserSuccess(response.data)))
      .catch(error => dispatch(getUserFailure(error)))
  )
);
```

here is my user reducer

```js
export default function user(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
      };
    case GET_USER_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and here is my root reducer

```js
export default combineReducers({
  user,
});
```

Comment: are all those extra commas and ellipses valid in the reactjs library or something?  Otherwise looks like bad javascript is your culprit.

Comment: nah bro :D I'ts airbnb react eslint config. I'll get errors without that commas

Answer (score 2):

You need to spread the data which comes for user, no need to assign it to `user`. Your reducer is in it already

```js
case GET_USER_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    ...action.user
  };
```

Comment: this case works only with single user object. If I'll try that with array of users then array will be destroyed

Answer (score 0):

If this reducer should update the state with the complete representation of the new user (and discard old data) you should just return the new user as state.

Can you give the following a shot?

```js
export default function user(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_USER_SUCCESS:
      return action.user;
    case GET_USER_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with this answer, because it does not return properties from the initial state, and if the object you are receiving from the action does not contain properties of the user reducers previous state, you are modifying the shape of the object in a way you might not expect. This can cause errors in your connected components where attributes that you expect to be defined are suddenly `undefined`. I would prefer to use the spread operator or object assign to combine the previous state with the payload of the action.

Comment: @YoWakita - I disagree, but it all depends on use case. If this is tracking a user whose logged out and logged in as a separate user, why would you want to have properties from the old user lingering in state?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this quote

> If I'll try that with array of users then array will be destroyed

Why not use Object.assign()?

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {user: [...state.user, ...action.user]})
```

Assuming that having multiple users is a possibility, why not just maintain the user property in your state as an array?

Comment: I just need to make 2 actions. First will get single user object from an API
and the second will get an array of multiple users from an API and I need to save them separately in the state.

Comment: If separately, then use two properties or if the api calls don't relate, then i'd suggest just using a separate reducer to handle the array of users.